# Convert decimal to hexadecimal in UNIX shell script

Tags: unix, shell, hex

In a UNIX shell script, what can I use to convert decimal numbers into hexadecimal?  I thought od would do the trick, but it's not realizing I'm feeding it ASCII representations of numbers.

printf?  Gross!  Using it for now, but what else is available?

Comment: I have to ask, what's gross about printf? Many common programming languages support printf-like formatting, so the printf solutions below would surely be the easiest for developers to understand.

Comment: Boy, I don't know - that was five years ago!  I think maybe I thought it wasn't true shell or something.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

```
echo "obase=16; 34" | bc
```

If you want to filter a whole file of integers, one per line:

```
( echo "obase=16" ; cat file_of_integers ) | bc
```

Comment: I looked at both bc(1) and dc(1) and missed that one.

Comment: Any way to turn it into a filter that'll take an arbitrary number of integers, all on one line?

Comment: @skiphoppy: If you write: echo "obase=16; 12 34 56" | bc you get 1E240, just the same as if you wrote: echo "obase=16; 123456" | bc.  So the way to deal with arbitrary numbers of integers all on one line is to put each number on its own line: tr ' ' '\015' <input | bc (map blanks to newlines).

Comment: This is great if you happen to have 'bc', but 'printf' is part of bash itself

Comment: @fuzzyTew, sure, that's true.  But only if you have bash. :-)

Comment: @Bill Karwin, or zsh, or busybox, but maybe not some shell I haven't tried?  I don't keep plain sh installed anymore
but clearly skiphoppy is looking for what other options there are

Comment: I like the piping aspect of this, but how do you do the reverse? From decimal to hexadecimal?

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat, this *is* decimal to hexadecimal. I assume you mean convert hex to dec. To do that, set `ibase=16`. You might like to read the [manual on bc](http://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html) for more details.

Comment: you would like to add that bc is case sensitive. meaning `echo "ibase=16; dead" | bc` will not work, you need to do `echo "ibase=16; DEAD" | bc`, I was bit surprised by this

Answer (score 221):

Tried `printf(1)`?

```
printf "%x\n" 34
22
```

There are probably ways of doing that with builtin functions in all shells but it would be less portable.  I've not checked the POSIX sh specs to see whether it has such capabilities.

Comment: Great, I needed to convert an IPv4 address to IPv6, this works!

Comment: It's doesn't get much more POSIX than printf.  This even works in "sh".

Comment: printf isn't aribtrary precision.  `bc` is.  for example, taking `238862874857408875879219909679752457540` as input, printf gives us "Result too large".  the BC method works great for things larger than a standard int/long/bigint

Comment: And, if you want uppercase letters in hex, use `printf "%X"` with uppercase X.

Comment: And to force an output like "0x00", you can use printf "0x%02X"

Comment: ... and `bc` is not available everywhere (at least not on my embedded Linux).

Comment: And don't forget the `-v VAR` as in `printf -v VAR "%x" 34 && echo $VAR`

Answer (score 79):

**Hexidecimal to decimal:**

```
$ echo $((0xfee10000))
4276158464
```

**Decimal to hexadecimal:**

```
$ printf '%x\n' 26
1a
```

Answer (score 18):

```
bash-4.2$ printf '%x\n' 4294967295
ffffffff

bash-4.2$ printf -v hex '%x' 4294967295
bash-4.2$ echo $hex
ffffffff
```

Comment: `-v VAR` is a bash extension. Not mentioned in the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/printf), revealed only if one calls `printf` without arguments

Comment: @AdrianW it's in the manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins

Comment: @AdrianW There's no dedicated man page for it because it's a bash builtin. Those are documented in `man bash`. Or, as with any builtin, you can do `help printf`. (`man printf` shows documentation for the separate, standalone program `printf`.)

Answer (score 7):

Sorry my fault, try this...

```
#!/bin/bash
:

declare -r HEX_DIGITS="0123456789ABCDEF"

dec_value=$1
hex_value=""

until [ $dec_value == 0 ]; do

    rem_value=$((dec_value % 16))
    dec_value=$((dec_value / 16))

    hex_digit=${HEX_DIGITS:$rem_value:1}

    hex_value="${hex_digit}${hex_value}"

done

echo -e "${hex_value}"
```

Example:

```
$ ./dtoh 1024
400
```

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot for env. where `printf` and `hex` commands are  not available.

Comment: @benchuk where is `printf` not available?

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
printf "%X\n" ${MY_NUMBER}
```

Comment: What is the difference between `$MY_NUMBER` and `${MY_NUMBER}` ?

Comment: @SasQ using brackets forces interpretation of the symbol that you intended to be used, i.e. just MY_NUMBER. Using brackets allows you to do things like ${MY_TEXT_FRAG_${MY_NUMBER}} to concatenate variable names.

Answer (score 3):

In `zsh` you can do this sort of thing:

```
% typeset -i 16 y
% print $(( [#8] x = 32, y = 32 ))
8#40
% print $x $y
8#40 16#20
% setopt c_bases
% print $y
0x20
```

Example taken from [`zsh` docs page about Arithmetic Evaluation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Arithmetic-Evaluation.html).

I believe Bash has similar capabilities.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I stumbled upon one issue with using printf solution:

`$ printf "%x" 008
bash: printf: 008: invalid octal number`

The easiest way was to use solution with *bc*, suggested in post higher:

`$ bc <<< "obase=16; 008"
8`

Comment: What does your solution add to the ones written years before?

Comment: @Matthieu It mentions the issue of numbers with leading zeros, which Bash printf unhelpfully interprets as octal, and demonstrates a solution that avoids the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
xd() {
    printf "hex> "
    while read i
    do
        printf "dec  $(( 0x${i} ))\n\nhex> "
    done
}
dx() {
    printf "dec> "
    while read i
    do
        printf 'hex  %x\n\ndec> ' $i
    done
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# number conversion.

while `test $ans='y'`
do
    echo "Menu"
    echo "1.Decimal to Hexadecimal"
    echo "2.Decimal to Octal"
    echo "3.Hexadecimal to Binary"
    echo "4.Octal to Binary"
    echo "5.Hexadecimal to  Octal"
    echo "6.Octal to Hexadecimal"
    echo "7.Exit"

    read choice
    case $choice in

        1) echo "Enter the decimal no."
           read n
           hex=`echo "ibase=10;obase=16;$n"|bc`
           echo "The hexadecimal no. is $hex"
           ;;

        2) echo "Enter the decimal no."
           read n
           oct=`echo "ibase=10;obase=8;$n"|bc`
           echo "The octal no. is $oct"
           ;;

        3) echo "Enter the hexadecimal no."
           read n
           binary=`echo "ibase=16;obase=2;$n"|bc`
           echo "The binary no. is $binary"
           ;;

        4) echo "Enter the octal no."
           read n
           binary=`echo "ibase=8;obase=2;$n"|bc`
           echo "The binary no. is $binary"
           ;;

        5) echo "Enter the hexadecimal no."
           read n
           oct=`echo "ibase=16;obase=8;$n"|bc`
           echo "The octal no. is $oct"
           ;;

        6) echo "Enter the octal no."
           read n
           hex=`echo "ibase=8;obase=16;$n"|bc`
           echo "The hexadecimal no. is $hex"
           ;;

        7) exit 
        ;;
        *) echo "invalid no." 
        ;;

    esac
done
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a shell script, but it is the cli tool I'm using to convert numbers among bin/oct/dec/hex:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl

    if (@ARGV < 2) {
      printf("Convert numbers among bin/oct/dec/hex\n");
      printf("\nUsage: base b/o/d/x num num2 ... \n");
      exit;
    }

    for ($i=1; $i<@ARGV; $i++) {
      if ($ARGV[0] eq "b") {
                    $num = oct("0b$ARGV[$i]");
      } elsif ($ARGV[0] eq "o") {
                    $num = oct($ARGV[$i]);
      } elsif ($ARGV[0] eq "d") {
                    $num = $ARGV[$i];
      } elsif ($ARGV[0] eq "h") {
                    $num = hex($ARGV[$i]);
      } else {
                    printf("Usage: base b/o/d/x num num2 ... \n");
                    exit;
      }
      printf("0x%x = 0d%d = 0%o = 0b%b\n", $num, $num, $num, $num);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**For those who would like to use variables, first export it by running:**

```
export NUM=100
```

**Then run:**

```
printf "%x\n" $NUM
```

**Else, you can you can ignore the use case of the variables and run it directly as shown below:**

```
printf "%x\n" 100
```

**NB:Substitute NUM with the variable name of your choice.**

*Exporting makes it an environmental variable(global).*

Answer (score -2):

Wow, I didn't realize that printf was available at the shell!

With that said, I'm surprised no-one commented about putting the printf into a shell script (which then you could put in your personal bin directory if you wanted).

echo "printf "0x%x\n" $1" > hex
chmod +x hex

Now just run:
./hex 123

It returns:
0x7b