# Hexadecimal To Decimal in Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell, hex, decimal

Can someone help me to convert a hexadecimal number to decimal number in a shell script?

E.g., I want to convert the hexadecimal number `bfca3000` to decimal using a shell script. I basically want the difference of two hexadecimal numbers.

My code is:

```
var3=`echo "ibase=16; $var1" | bc`
var4=`echo "ibase=16; $var2" | bc`
var5=$(($var4-$var3))               # [Line 48]
```

When executing, I get this error:

```
Line 48: -: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "-")
```

Comment: The other way around: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378829/convert-decimal-to-hexadecimal-in-unix-shell-script. Essentially the same tools. And possible cross site duplicate of: http://superuser.com/questions/226163/linux-shell-utils-convert-a-list-of-hex-to-list-of-decimals

Answer (score 448, accepted):

To convert from hex to decimal, there are many ways to do it in the shell or with an external program:

With [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

```
$ echo $((16#FF))
255
```

with [bc](/questions/tagged/bc):

```
$ echo "ibase=16; FF" | bc
255
```

with [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
$ perl -le 'print hex("FF");'
255
```

with [printf](/questions/tagged/printf) :

```
$ printf "%d\n" 0xFF
255
```

with [python](/questions/tagged/python):

```
$ python -c 'print(int("FF", 16))'
255
```

with [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby):

```
$ ruby -e 'p "FF".to_i(16)'
255
```

with [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js):

```
$ node -e "console.log(parseInt('FF', 16))"
255
```

with [rhino](/questions/tagged/rhino):

```
$ rhino -e "print(parseInt('FF', 16))"
255
```

with [groovy](/questions/tagged/groovy):

```
$ groovy -e 'println Integer.parseInt("FF",16)'
255
```

Comment: Is the `printf` solution POSIX? If yes, it's the best :)

Comment: In bash you can also use `$((0xff))`, i.e. with C-like hex prefix instead of `16#`, although `N#` is clearly more general.

Comment: The first bash example is susceptible to integer overflow error, e.g. `echo $((077E9F2DBF49D100001#FF))` overflows the 64-bit integer limit of 2^64. `bc` handles this properly.

Comment: lspci to xorg.conf PCI ID transform, just in case:
`lspci -d ::0300 | cut -f1 -d' ' | ( IFS=":." read b d f; printf "PCI:%02d:%02d:%02d\n" 0x$b 0x$d 0x$f )`

Comment: ```bash
~ 
➜ node <<< "console.log(0x1f)" 
31
```

Comment: It seems dumb that `bc` only accepts uppercase hex. So this doesn't work: `echo "ibase=16; 2f" | bc`

Comment: @CraigMcQueen To me it seems dumb that people use lower case hex to begin with. Digits are basically upper case letters, as upper case is the normal form of all letters, lower case is a form that just go added later in history and just was never added to digits. Digits are also always full line height, like all upper case letters. Traditional hex has always been upper case, lower case was only allowed so lazy people didn't have to press shift key.

Comment: @CiroSantilliOurBigBook.com `printf` is POSIX and it is the recommend command to use whenever feeding anything into a command, since the behavior of `echo` is not fully standardized by the POSIX standard and may vary between systems (e.g. the exact behavior `-n` flag is implementation defined and may not even supress a line break), whereas `printf` is fully standardized.  `echo` is really just intended for writing text to screen to be read by the user and nothing else.

Comment: @Mecki beware that although `printf` is POSIX, POSIX does not include the flag `-v` that set result to a shell variable, which is `bash` only.  `x=$((0x${hex}))` is AFAIK the only POSIX and efficient way to set converted decimal to a variable.

Answer (score 58):

Dealing with a very lightweight embedded version of busybox on Linux means many of the traditional commands are not available (bc, printf, dc, perl, python)

```
echo $((0x2f))
47

hexNum=2f
echo $((0x${hexNum}))
47
```

Credit to [Peter Leung](http://linuxcommando.blogspot.com/2008/04/quick-hex-decimal-conversion-using-cli.html) for this solution.

Comment: OK but beware of integer overflow error, e.g. `echo $((0x077E9F2DBF49D100001))` overflows the 64-biit integer limit of 2^64. `bc` handles this properly

Comment: Indeed `echo` has limitations and `bc` solves them, but [Busybox](https://busybox.net) does [currently not have `bc` among the applets](https://web.archive.org/web/20210406101850/https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#commands). Hopefully it does in the future.

Comment: syntax error in expression (error token is "3")

Comment: +1 for being the only POSIX way to convert hex to dec without shelling out just to set a shell variable.  All other POSIX utility requires a sub-shell to do so.  Ref: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04

Comment: IMO, as long as you are aware of the issue that @roblogic mentioned, you can safely use this method.  For number values that overflows shell limit, you probably should NOT be using the shell to do it.

Answer (score 17):

One more way to do it using the shell (bash or ksh, doesn't work with dash):

```
echo $((16#FF))
255
```

Comment: What does the `#` symbol mean? Are there any other applications or documentation to read more about its use?

Comment: It is mentioned here: [link](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic) . At the end of section 6.5 it says: "...numbers take the form [base#]n, where the optional base is a decimal number between 2 and 64 representing the arithmetic base, and n is a number in that base. If base# is omitted, then base 10 is used. The digits greater than 9 are represented by the lowercase letters, the uppercase letters, ‘@’, and ‘_’, in that order. If base is less than or equal to 36, lowercase and uppercase letters may be used interchangeably to represent numbers between 10 and 35."

Comment: The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22863296/29290) by [@hinekyle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1810139/hinekyle) using `echo $((0x2f))` does work with `dash` (tested on "BusyBox v1.29.3 (2019-05-21 15:22:06 PDT) multi-call binary." that is part of VMware ESXi 6.5 update 3).

Answer (score 14):

Various tools are available to you from within a shell.  Sputnick has given you an excellent overview of your options, based on your initial question.  He definitely deserves votes for the time he spent giving you multiple correct answers.

One more that's not on his list:

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ dc -e '16i BFCA3000 p'
3217698816
```

But if all you want to do is subtract, why bother changing the input to base 10?

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ dc -e '16i BFCA3000 17FF - p 10o p'
3217692673
BFCA1801
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

The `dc` command is "desk calc".  It will also take input from stdin, like `bc`, but instead of using "order of operations", it uses stacking ("reverse Polish") notation.  You give it inputs which it adds to a stack, then give it operators that pop items off the stack, and push back on the results.

In the commands above we've got the following:

- **`16i`** -- tells dc to accept input in base 16 (hexadecimal). Doesn't change output base.
- **`BFCA3000`** -- your initial number
- **`17FF`** -- a random hex number I picked to subtract from your initial number
- **`-`** -- take the two numbers we've pushed, and subtract the later one from the earlier one, then push the result back onto the stack
- **`p`** -- print the last item on the stack.  This doesn't change the stack, so...
- **`10o`** -- tells dc to print its output in base "10", but remember that our input numbering scheme is currently hexadecimal, so "10" means "16".
- **`p`** -- print the last item on the stack again ... this time in hex.

You can construct fabulously complex math solutions with dc.  It's a good thing to have in your toolbox for shell scripts.

Answer (score 10):

In dash and other shells, you can use

```
printf "%d\n" (your hexadecimal number)
```

to convert a hexadecimal number to decimal.
This is not specific to bash or ksh.

Comment: e.g. `printf "%d" 0xff`

Comment: Also solution for unsigned 64-bit values with `printf "%u" 0xff`

Answer (score 4):

The error as reported appears when the variables are null (or empty):

```
$ unset var3 var4; var5=$(($var4-$var3))
bash: -: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "-")
```

That could happen because the value given to bc was incorrect. That might well be that bc needs UPPERcase values. It needs `BFCA3000`, not `bfca3000`. That is easily fixed in bash, just use the `^^` expansion:

```
var3=bfca3000; var3=`echo "ibase=16; ${var1^^}" | bc`
```

That will change the script to this:

```
#!/bin/bash

var1="bfca3000"
var2="efca3250"

var3="$(echo "ibase=16; ${var1^^}" | bc)"
var4="$(echo "ibase=16; ${var2^^}" | bc)"

var5="$(($var4-$var3))"

echo "Diference $var5"
```

But there is no need to use bc [1], as bash could perform the translation and substraction directly:

```
#!/bin/bash

var1="bfca3000"
var2="efca3250"

var5="$(( 16#$var2 - 16#$var1 ))"

echo "Diference $var5"
```

[1]<sup>Note: I am assuming the values could be represented in 64 bit math, as the difference was calculated in bash in your original script. Bash is limited to integers less than ((2**63)-1) if compiled in 64 bits. That will be the only difference with bc which does not have such limit.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Shortest way yet:

```
$ echo $[0x3F]
63
```

Comment: This syntax is discouraged by Chet Ramey himself. Use `$((0x3f))`

Answer (score 2):

I have this handy script on my $PATH to filter `0x1337`-like; `1337`; or `"0x1337"` lines of input into decimal strings (expanded for clarity):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read data; do
  withoutQuotes=`echo ${data} | sed s/\"//g`
  without0x=`echo ${withoutQuotes} | sed s/0x//g`
  clean=${without0x}
  echo $((16#${clean}))
done
```