# Use sed te extract ascii hex string from a single line in a file

Tags: bash, shell, sed, hex, ascii

I have a file that looks like this:

```
some random
text
00ab46f891c2emore random
text
234324fc234ba253069
and yet more text
```

only one line in the file contains only hex characters (`234324fc234ba253069`), how do I extract that? I tried `sed -ne 's/^\([a-f0-9]*\)$/\1/p' file` I used line start and line end (`^` and `&`) as delimiters, but I am obviously missing something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grep does the job,

```
$ grep '^[a-f0-9]\+$' file
234324fc234ba253069
```

Through awk,

```
$ awk '/^[a-f0-9]+$/{print}' file
234324fc234ba253069
```

Based on the search pattern given, `awk` and `grep` prints the matched line.

```
^             # start
[a-f0-9]\+    # hex characters without capital A-F one or more times
$             # End
```

Comment: for some weird reason neither
`sed -ne 's/^\([a-f0-9]*\)$/\1/p' file`
nor
`sed -n '/^[a-f0-9]*$/p' file`
nor
`sed -n '/^[a-f0-9]*$/{p;q}'`
works on my system (???)
I don't like a while loop and don't have `egrep` on that machine, so I am, again, thanking you for the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

`sed` can make it:

```
sed -n '/^[a-f0-9]*$/p' file
234324fc234ba253069
```

By the way, your command `sed -ne 's/^\([a-f0-9]*\)$/\1/p' file` is working to me. Note, also, that it is not necessary to use `\1` to print back. It is handy in many cases, but now it is too much because you want to print the whole line. Just `sed -n '/pattern/p'` does the job, as I indicate above.

As there is just one match in the whole file, you may want to exit once it is found ([thanks NeronLeVelu!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24246897/use-sed-te-extract-ascii-hex-string-from-a-single-line-in-a-file/24246953?noredirect=1#comment37451983_24246953)):

```
sed -n '/^[a-f0-9]*$/{p;q}' file
```

---

Another approach is to let `printf` decide when the line is hexadecimal:

```
while read line
do
    printf "%f\n" "0x"$line >/dev/null 2>&1  && echo "$line"
done < file
```

Based on [Hexadecimal To Decimal in Shell Script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13280173/1983854), `printf "%f" 0xNUMBER` executes successfully if the number is indeed hexadecimal. Otherwise, it returns an error.
Hence, using `printf ... >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "$line"` does not let `printf` print anything (redirects to `/dev/null`) but then prints the line if it was hexadecimal.

For your given file, it returns:

```
$ while read line; do printf "%f\n" "0x"$line >/dev/null 2>&1  && echo "$line"; done < a
234324fc234ba253069
```

Comment: i propose to adapt  the end `p` by `{p;q;}` to speed up a bit on long file

Comment: Good point, @NeronLeVelu , hadn't notices about the unique match. Thanks, just updated :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `egrep` you can restrict your regex to select lines that only match valid hex characters i.e. `[a-fA-F0-9]`:

```
egrep '^[a-fA-F0-9]+$' file
234324fc234ba253069
```