# Writing a one-liner tool in Python for converting hex into decimal

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working in an embedded environment which has `python` but not `bc`. I had a need to convert a hex number from stdin into a decimal value.

I have found a solution and I'm suspecting that others might also be interested in a solution for this simple task.

So lets say I want something like this:

```
$ echo "ff" | [something in python]
255
```

Comment: Honestly, this is just a trivial combination of "How do I take user input?", "How do I convert a hex string to a number?", and "How do I run a python command from the command line?".

Answer (score 2):

So here is a detailed answer:

1. For reading the input, we can use python3's **input()** function.
2. For converting a number from hex to int, we can use **int()** with 16 as its second parameter.
3. For specifying a code to run in the command line, we use the `-c` option.

Putting all of this together, we are getting:

```
echo "ff" | python3 -c 'a=input();print(int(a,16))'
255
```

Comment: You could directly use `print(int(input(),16))` (without the `a`)

Comment: You can just use bash directly instead of having to summon Python at all: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280131/hexadecimal-to-decimal-in-shell-script