# Convert varible to number for dd command using Shell script

Tags: linux, shell, dd

I parsed `/proc/PID/maps` using shell script , now I have 2 variable

```
START_ADDR=982fe000
END_ADDR=984fe000
```

I want to use those variable for `dd` using shell script command like:

```
dd if=SOME_MEMORY skip=START_ADDR count=(END_ADDR-START_ADDR) of=out.bin bs=1
```

How can I convert those variable for dd?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hexadecimal To Decimal in Shell Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280131/hexadecimal-to-decimal-in-shell-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you didn't mention which shell you are using, I am assuming you are using `bash`.
Keeping that in mind, you can modify your above command as shown below to make it work.

```
dd if=$SOME_MEMORY skip=$START_ADDR count=$((0x$END_ADDR - 0x$START_ADDR)) of=out.bin bs=1
```

You need to make sure the variables `SOME_MEMORY`, `END_ADDR` and `START_ADDR` are accessible and present in current shell environment, to verify you can do
`echo $SOME_MEMORY`, `echo $START_ADDR` and similarly `echo $END_ADDR`