# Convert hex file names to decim

Tags: linux, bash, shell, hex, decimal

I have several files named in a hex format. I'd like to mass rename them into their decimal equivalents, turning them from

1. `0x000f750d.wav`
2. `0x000f750e.wav`
3. `0x000f750f.wav`

to

1. `1013005.wav`
2. `1013006.wav`
3. `1013007.wav`

I've tried the following command in order to fetch the files' names in decimal and rename them, but I'm unsure how to go about it. (Note: before this command, I removed the .wav extensions from the files with the intent of readding them later to make it easier on myself.)

```
for f in *; do
    mv -- "$(($f))" $f;
done
```

This is the result:

```
mv: cannot stat '1013005': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat '1013006': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat '1013007': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat '0': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the only errors you get? `bash: 0x000f750d.wav: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".wav")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hexadecimal To Decimal in Shell Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280131/hexadecimal-to-decimal-in-shell-script)

Comment: I removed the .wav extensions from the files to make it easier on myself with the intent of adding them later, since otherwise the error tink mentioned pops up. `$(())` won't accept the file extension itself as part of it.

Comment: I think you're almost there, but you have to swap the arguments to `mv`: first the current filename, then the decimal version using `$((...))`. Also, you should quote `"$f"`.

Comment: See _man mv_ : First comes the souce, then the destination. There is a pattern to this: `cp`, `ln` and `rsync` for instance behave in the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically had it, but with the wrong order of arguments. This should work, and removes the extension for `$((...))`, then adds it back:

```bash
for f in *; do mv -- "$f" "$((${f/%.wav})).wav"; done
```

Comment: You learn something new every day. Thanks a ton!