# How to print only the hex values from hexdump without the line numbers or the ASCII table?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, hexdump

following [Convert decimal to hexadecimal in UNIX shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378829/convert-decimal-to-hexadecimal-in-unix-shell-script)

I am trying to print only the `hex values` from `hexdump`, i.e. don't print the lines numbers and the ASCII table.

But the following command line doesn't print anything:

```
hexdump -n 50 -Cs 10 file.bin |  awk '{for(i=NF-17; i>2; --i) print $i}'
```

Comment: age is not the primary factor, but rather upvotes and answer quality ;-) http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251938/should-i-flag-a-question-as-duplicate-if-it-has-received-better-answers

Comment: hexdump file.bin | sed "s/[^ ]* //1" This will remove the line numbers, by default the ascii table wouldn't be printed.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can specify the exact format that you want `hexdump` to use for output, but it's a bit tricky. Here's the default output, minus the file offsets:

```
hexdump -e '16/1 "%02x " "\n"' file.bin
```

(To me, it looks like this would produce an extra trailing space at the end
of each line, but for some reason it doesn't.)

Comment: Great!! Usefull for me this answer! But I think is better also to have `-C` option. And if you add `cut -c 9- | head -n 1` your output will display only the hex numbers.

Comment: [This blog entry](https://blog.senpaisilver.com/linux/formatting-hexdumps-output/) shows more examples how to modify the output format of `hexdump`.

Comment: Add `-v` to list every line and not to compress same lines with `*`

Answer (score 85):

Using `xxd` might be a better option for this task:

```
xxd -p -l 50 -seek 10 file.bin
```

From [`man xxd`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xxd):

```
xxd - make a hexdump or do the reverse.

    -p | -ps | -postscript | -plain
        output in postscript continuous hexdump style. Also known as plain hexdump style.

    -l len | -len len
        stop after writing <len> octets.
 
    -seek offset
        When used after -r: revert with <offset> added to file positions found in hexdump.
```

Comment: @andsens `hexdump` is in busybox, and thus available on embedded, whilst `xxd` isn't :Ь

Answer (score 30):

As an alternative, consider using `xxd -p file.bin`.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, remove `-C` which is emitting the ascii information.

Then you could drop the offset with

```
hexdump -n 50 -s 10 file.bin | cut -c 9-
```

Comment: it seems to work but changes the endian...