# Invalid number (error token is "16##0x00a002")

Tags: shell, sh

I want to convert a hexadecimal value to decimal value, perform some arithmetic operation and convert it back to hexadecimal.
In an attempt to do so, I am facing the following error,

> "myshell.sh: line 77: 16##0x00a002: invalid number (error token is
>   "16##0x00a002")

The related line of code is:

```
SUBVER3_1=$((16##$SUBVER3_1))
```

Can someone let me know:

1. What this error is and how can i fix it?
2. How to perform arithmetic operations on hexadecimal numbers in shell?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert decimal to hexadecimal in UNIX shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378829/convert-decimal-to-hexadecimal-in-unix-shell-script)

Comment: Your script snippet is not valid `sh` -- you should probably tag it with one of `bash` (IMHO the most probable), `ksh`, or `zsh`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `0x` prefix is not valid for base 16 notation.  Strip it before converting.  Also, if you are using Bash, the syntax for base conversion uses a single `#` after the base.

```
SUBVER3_1=$((16#${SUBVER3_1#0x}))
```

This uses the traditional POSIX `${variable#prefix}` notation to strip off a prefix.  The `#` in that is unrelated to the `base#string` notation.

The shell supports basic integer arithmetic.  The arithmetic operations are independent of the base you are using; simple addition etc like `$((255+255))` can use base-16 notation just as well `$((16#FF+16#FF))` but keep in mind that division with only integers is of rather limited usefulness.  If you want results in hex, `printf` can do that:

```
printf "%04x\n" $((16#ff + 16#ff))
```

Comment: Is the `16##` a shell-specific feature, or something specified by POSIX?

Comment: It's not in POSIX, though I believe `ksh` and `zsh` support something similar, too.  The OP uses Bash arithmetic evaluation syntax so that's what I'm guessing they are actually using.

Comment: [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04) does seem to indicate support for the `0x` prefix itself though.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is now resolved,
I used print statement to fix this issue instead of the above statement

SUBVER3_1=$(printf "%x" $SUBVER3_1) # Converting from decimal to hexadecimal

This served the purpose