# Converting decimal to hexadecimal in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, hex, decimal

I want to convert a decimal number (loop index number) in a bash script to hexadecimal to be used by another command. Something like:

```
for ((i=1; i<=100; i++))
do

     a=convert-to-decimal($i)
     echo "$a"

done
```

Where **a** should be hexadecimal with four digits and hex identifier. For example if value of **i** is **100**, the value of **a** should be **0x0064**. How to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert decimal to hexadecimal in UNIX shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378829/convert-decimal-to-hexadecimal-in-unix-shell-script)

Comment: `printf "%#06x" 100` → `0x0064`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`printf`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-printf).

```
$ printf "0x%04x" 100
0x0064
```

In your example you'd probably use `a="$(printf '0x%04x' $i)"`.

Comment: Or `printf -v a '0x%04x' $i` instead of process substitution.

Comment: @BenjaminW. You certainly mean _command substitution._ But your point is correct.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I absolutely do!

Comment: Actually 0x can be left off. `#` flag adds this automatically. So `printf "%#06x" 100` gives `0x0064`. The only question remains if the OP needs lower case of upper case hex digits. In the later case the `X` specifier should be used.

Comment: @TrueY: feel free to edit the answer to improve it! (or write your own answer).

Answer (score 1):

That's what you're looking for

for i in `seq 1 100`;
do
     printf '%x\n' $i
done