# How to get a snapshot image of running window in Xorg?

Tags: image, screenshot, xorg

I wanted to migrate Compiz's Window Picker function to XFCE environment , so i needed to grab an image of the window running in current display , and display it with an `GtkWidget` , but how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind relying on an external tool, you can acquire the image by invoking ImageMagick's `import -window 0xid bmp-`. Read the output from a pipe and create the appropriate GTK object.

Of course, you will to replace the window ID you want to get the image from. Here is [a post that will help you get the window ID from a a Process ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151407/how-to-get-an-x11-window-from-a-process-id).

Comment: actually i should take a look at xwd.c , but thanks anyway , i'm closing this thread.