# detecting the "main" windows on X11 by pid.

Tags: c, window, x11, pid

When I query application windows by pid. By iterating the window tree. I get a few windows associated for that process. 
For example if I have an app running with only has one windows showing I still get bunch of windows associated with the process ID when I query the windows manager for windows under that PID.

I followed this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151407/how-to-get-an-x11-window-from-a-process-id)

How do I determine which window is the Main application window. Say I am running firefox, I am looking for the app windows, which all the tabs are underneath.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check [_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html#idm140200472629520) property, for main window it should be _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL