# How to find the Application Name from a process in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, windows

I'm writing a python script to get the running process and their "application name" (e.g. chrome.exe -> Google Chrome). I've no problem to find process name (chrome.exe), but how can I find the application name?

I've already written a database (columns are: processName appName category), but there is another way to get these info using only python? (I would like to use this script on Windows-Linux-MacOS).

Any idea?

Comment: There are no "applications" on Linux (and probably on MacOS, either). Only processes.

Comment: yeah I know, that's why I used an example. I would like to get for any process, the name we see (another example: if the process is "soffice.bin", I see LibreOffice. And I want to get the name I see)

Comment: That's the window name. [This may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151407/how-to-get-an-x11-window-from-a-process-id)

Comment: Task Manager uses the file description from the PE image, which you can query via `win32api.GetFileVersionInfo`.

Comment: For example, to list the file description in all available translations: `exe = r'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe';` `blk_trans = r'\VarFileInfo\Translation';` `blk_descr = r'\StringFileInfo\{:04x}{:04x}\FileDescription';` `trans = win32api.GetFileVersionInfo(exe, blk_trans);` `for t in trans: win32api.GetFileVersionInfo(exe, blk_descr.format(*t))`.

Comment: @ErykSun yeah but it works only in Windows I think, I need something for Linux and MacOS as well

Comment: @DYZ yes but it's C++... Do you know any alternatives in Python?

Comment: Determining the user-facing representation of a process' name is inherently platform-specific. Unless there is a Python module that wraps the platform-specific implementation behind a platform-agnostic interface you will be writing platform-specific code.

Comment: In Windows you could also go a step further to look for a UWP app name. For macOS, maybe look for a plist for an application bundle. For Linux, maybe support Snap apps (snaps), but otherwise I think mapping a binary to an application package will be expensive and dependent on the distro.

Comment: @IInspectable I guessed,  what about a kind of database I talked before? Processes name are similar for operative systems... Using a fuzzy library I can get similar processes and then I can give them the name I want, is it less expensive?

Comment: @ErykSun thanks for answering me with details for each os. Can you give me an opinion as well about my previous answer above?

Comment: How does a database fare in face of applications you do not know? That includes the unbounded set of applications that have not yet been released.

Comment: I suppose to know every program is running. If i don't know it, probably is system's. If it has just been installed, I create a kind of module to save this app with a name and a category choosen by me