# How to get window IDs for Qt's fromWinId

Tags: c++, qt, x11

I am currently on Qt5, and want to emulate Qt4's X11EmbedWidget, which has been removed. All sources I can find online point me to using `QWindow::fromWinId` to make the native window into a QT window, then using `QWidget::createWindowContainer()` to put the window into another.

I am creating the child process using fork and execve, like so

```
pid_t pid = fork();

if (pid == 0) {
  //child
  execv("./application.bin", NULL);
  exit(0);
} else {
  //parent

  //get window ID
  //use createWindowContainer
}
```

i just can't seem to get the window ID with this. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/151407/18385579) post, but it gives an empty list every time. Is there any way to do this directly from execv() or fork()?

Comment: fork will not create a window so how should fork return such an id? You have to pass it to the calling application somehow (e.g. through stdout)

Answer (score 0):

I realized my error. The reason the window ID outputted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151407/how-to-get-an-x11-window-from-a-process-id) answer always gives 0 is because I was trying to fetch the ID right after the execv(). I added in a usleep(3e4) before trying to get the window ID and it worked well.