# Is there any way to use Xephyr as a QT Widget?

Tags: c, qt, x11

I learned of the tool known as [Xephyr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xephyr) recently, and was wondering if I could use it in a QT widget. What I am envisioning is an embedded Xephyr, or any X11 server really, instance running in a small corner of my Qt window. Is what I am asking for impossible?

I know about the X11 embed protocol, and that I can embed an application in my Qt window with it, but for experimental purposes I want to see if using a nested X server is possible.

Comment: The new 'root' window created by Xephyr is an X11 window just like any other.  So just use its window id when you call `QWidget::createWindowContainer(QWindow::fromWinId(xephyr_wid))`.

Comment: @G.M. I tried using Xephyr's `-parent` option in the command line, but I get an X11 error saying `Error code: 8
Sequence number: 5
Major code: 1   Minor code: 0
Error value: 50331654`. And when I try to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151407/how-to-get-an-x11-window-from-a-process-id) answer to just get the window ID of Xephyr to attach that way, it yields 0. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found some messy way to embed Xephyr into QT5+.
You have to create new QMainWindow and set this window as parent of Xephyr's window.
Then show and close this newly created QMainWindow.
Now you should be able to insert Xephyr into QT widget.

```
void MainWindow::reparentXWindow() {
    QVBoxLayout *box = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    QMainWindow *window = new QMainWindow();
    QWidget *widget = QWidget::createWindowContainer(QWindow::fromWinId(this->mWinid)); //Xephyr's WinId
    widget->setParent(window);
    window->lower();
    window->show();
    window->close();
    QTimer::singleShot(50, this, SLOT(embedXWindow()));
}

void MainWindow::embedXWindow() {
    QWidget *widget = QWidget::createWindowContainer(QWindow::fromWinId(this->mWinid)); //Xephyr's WinId
    /*QVboxLayout*/ ui->vbox->addWidget(widget);
}
```

You may need to reshape the widget after killing everything from Xephyr*